# Mongoose Db: How can I use a parameterized method in a Mongoose query?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema, 
    ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

var Group = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    members: [{ type: ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],
    leader: { type: ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
    // more fields to filter by
});


Group.method('role', function (user) {
    if (this.leader === user) return "Leader";
    else if (this.members.indexOf(user) >= 0) return "Member";
    else return "Non-Member";
});
```

I'm a Mongoose newbie and my first real query was a tricky one. I need to select a set of groups an display group name and the role of the current user (user_id is stored in session variable).

Can I use the 'role' method in a Mongoose select query?

Perhaps I should use a custom Node stream and implement the role method there?

I'm note sure that my conditions (this.leader === user) or (this.members.indexOf(user) >= 0) are correct or efficient.  I need to avoid loading the User object for every Group document.

Code example needed.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Perhaps this should be implemented using map-reduce?

Comment: Perhaps this should be implemented using map-reduce and generate a collection indexed by user_id that tracks the groups the user is either leading or a member of.  Membership rarely changes so this is probably the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

what you want to use is the aggregation framework

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/

You might need to dip down into the native driver for this query.